# Random Value Generation in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of values in Sheet-2 from column2 to column4. I want to generate output like this in my sheet3 randomly with the unique data that I have in each columns on sheet-2. Can we generate random values between text string.

Sheet2:

```
Column 2 Column 3 Column 4
M         25          Agree
F         48          Agree
          50          DisAgree
```

I want to generate random 120 rows of data in sheet3, something like this.

```
Column 2 Column3 Column4
M         25      Agree
F         48      DisAgree
M         48      Agree
M         50      DisAgree
.
.
.
.
M        25      Agree
```

To make it clear,

I have three columns - Column2, Column 3, Column4

In Sheet2, only the unique values are present. Same value inside that column will not be present.

In Sheet3, For Example, if we take column 2 alone. It has to have the values randomly from row2 to row 121 like M, F, F, M, F ( Randomly till 121st row).

Kindly Share your thoughts.

Comment: I'm a little confused - how does Sheet2's data get used in Sheet3? I don't see `F/25/DisAgree` in sheet2's table you showed.  If you want random values, do you need VBA? Why not do like (for the age) `=RANDBETWEEN(25,50)`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Sorry F25 doesn't exist in sheet2. Sorry mate.

Comment: But its not randbetween(25,50). Its just random between the values inside that particular column. So, its actually 25 and 50.

Comment: ...still unclear, where does `M/48/Agree` come from in sheet3?  Please expand and clarify your post.

Comment: @BruceWayne Please see the question now. I have updated the question.

Comment: "Same value inside that column will not be present" - you have "Agree" twice in column D.  (I assumed that was so that you would have a 2:1 weighting toward agree in your random values.)

Comment: @YowE3K yes. exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OFFSET` and `RANDBETWEEN` functions.

For instance:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!D$1,RANDBETWEEN(0,2),0)
```

That will select a random number between 0 and 2, and then select the value that many rows below Sheet2!D1.  So, if the random number generated was 2, it would return "Disagree".

Just set the second parameter of the `RANDBETWEEN` function to be one less than the number of choices available. (You could generalise that by using something like `COUNTA(Sheet2!D:D)-1` as the second parameter.)

---

Assuming both your sheets have headers in row 1, and therefore your data starts in row 2, you could use the following formula in Sheet3!B2 and copy it to the entire range of Sheet3!B2:D121

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!B$2,RANDBETWEEN(0,COUNTA(Sheet2!B:B)-2),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This checks the columns in sheet2 for the dataset count and generates a random number for the row that the data is taken from. It pastes the data into Sheet3. You can modify the for Loop for number and range of datasets to paste in.

```
Sub Random()
Dim lr1, lr2, lr3 As Long
Dim r1, r2, r3 As Integer
Dim sht, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet3")

lr1 = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lr3 = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To 120
r1 = CInt((lr1 - 1 + 1) * Rnd()) + 1
r2 = CInt((lr2 - 1 + 1) * Rnd()) + 1
r3 = CInt((lr3 - 1 + 1) * Rnd()) + 1

sht2.Cells(i, 1).Value = sht.Cells(r1, 1).Value
sht2.Cells(i, 2).Value = sht.Cells(r2, 2).Value
sht2.Cells(i, 3).Value = sht.Cells(r3, 3).Value

Next i

End Sub
```